# How to restrict cut copy past option for entire column

Tags: excel, vba

Per attached excel sheet, user should not able to cut copy and past for column "B" dropDown list.
User should able select data only from available dropDown list option

Sample Excel sheet with dropList
[image: Sample Excel sheet with dropList]

Could you please help me for the VBAMacros code.
Have tried multiple option, but no luck.

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Or 
  Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                       Application.Undo
```

Comment: You cannot really block copy paste that is not supported.

Comment: THanks!
Can we use VBA macro code?

Comment: No, you can't block it. If it is in the list fo the drop down you are able to paste it.

Comment: Rethink your goal and how it can be achieved without restrictions.

Comment: Perhaps you could write some VBA that changes the range selected to just a single cell. It won't stop them copying individual cells, but could prevent them from selecting the whole column / range within it?

Comment: For ex: If User "A" he updated Name, while selecting City instead if selecting option from dropdown list, if he past any random string he should get it alert "Please select a valid option from dropdown!"

Could u plz let me why its not possible thru VBA-Macros!

Comment: @joe J: Could u please share the VBA code for entire column "B"

Comment: Use a `Worksheet_Change` event and loop through every cell in the `Intersect`ion of column B and `Target`, validating that its `Value` is a valid option from the dropdown.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo handler
Debug.Print "change Selection"
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Or Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Undo
MsgBox "Data Invalid for restricted cells!"
Application.EnableEvents = True
Range("A1:A1").Select
Exit Sub
End If
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a bit of a workaround because you can't really prevent the user from copying if they can select the cell.

The alternative is to change the current selection to the first cell in the range if they select more than one cell. Put this code in the worksheet in selection change:

```
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Target.Cells(1).Select
```

This will end up with something like this in your worksheet VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Target.Cells(1).Select
End Sub
```

**Edit** 
The above is for preventing range selection on the whole sheet. If you just want to prevent it in column B use this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target.Worksheet.Columns(2), Target) Is Nothing Then Target.Cells(1).Select
End Sub
```

This also prevent selecting across column B (e.g. from A:C)

Comment: I have used same code, however its not working.
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 

      If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Or 
                  Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
                      If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                       Application.Undo
End if

Comment: @prasadsangpal see the update for just column B